# Integrating Google Firebase Firestore with ChatGPT API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, chatbot, chatgpt-api

Is it possible that the user asks whatever to the ChatGPT, and respectively it collects data from the Firebase Firestore database, and shows the data to the user as output?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: 2023-07-11

Nowadays there is a new extension called [Chatbot with ChatGPT](https://extensions.dev/extensions/shiftescape/firestore-chatgpt-bot). If you're looking to use this extension in an Android app, then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-chatbot-with-firebase-firestore-and-chatgpt-on-android-910dd40f11d9) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreChatGPT).

---

Currently, there is no integration between Firestore and ChatGPT. However, such an integration can be made using Cloud Functions or a Firebase Extension.

If you need something that already exists, then you can create a [Chatbot with PaLM API](https://extensions.dev/extensions/googlecloud/firestore-palm-chatbot):

> Use this extension to easily deploy a chatbot using the PaLM API, stored and managed by Cloud Firestore.

This feature was recently launched at [Google I/O 2023](https://firebase.blog/posts/2023/05/whats-new-at-google-io/).

If you're looking to see how this extension works in an Android app, then I think that the following resource will help:

- https://medium.com/@alex.mamo/e78549814aa

Here is the corresponding repo:

- https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestorePaLM

Comment: The answer to "is A possible" is seldom just "no" when it comes to software that has APIs. There is no pre-built integration between Firestore and ChatGPT, but nothing keeps OP (or someone who lands here in the future) from building that themselves with Cloud Functions - or maybe even as a Firebase Extension nowadays.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's correct. I just updated my answer. Thank you, puf.

Comment: Yes , this answer is very helpful . Can I use any third party API to integrating Google Firebase Firestore with ChatGPT API ?

Comment: It may exist but currently, I'm not aware of such APIs.

Comment: Hey Sanchita. Can I help you with other information?